# How do I prove the following WITHOUT using the open mapping theorem?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I want to prove the following claim:

Claim: Suppose $H$ and $K$ are Hilbert spaces. Let $T$ be a bounded and injective linear operator from $H$ to $K$. If the range of $T$ is closed, then there is a constant $c > 0$ such that $\|Tx\| \ge c\|x\|$ for all $x\in H$.

I know that using the open mapping theorem proves this pretty easily, but I would like to know if one can prove this WITHOUT using the open mapping theorem.

Here is what I tried.

Let $J$ be an inverse operator of T defined as $J(T(h))=h$ for every $h \in H$.

Then, to show $J$ is bounded, I assumed to the contrary that $J$ is not bounded. Then, for every natural number $n$, there exists $k_n$ in $K$ such that $\|J(k_n)\| > n\|k_n\|$. Then, I wanted to use the fact that the range of T is closed to draw contradiction, but I could not proceed..

How can I show the above claim?

Comment: I think you're stuck with the Baire Category Theorem in one form or another.